# Nested ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

I have the following JSON:

```
{ "ListNhomThanhTra": [
    {
        "ListKeHoachThanhTra": [
            {
                "ListDoiTuong": [
                    {
                        "MA_DV_DUOC_TT": "DT01",
                        "TEN_DOITUONG": "Tỉnh Bắc Ninh",
                        "stt": 1.1
                    }
                ],
                "MA_DM_KEHOACH_TT": "KH13072018003",
                "TEN_KEHOACH": "Kế hoạch chính thức",
                "stt": 1
            }
        ],
        "MA_NHOM_TT": "010",
        "TEN_NHOM": "Thanh tra ngân sách địa phương",
        "stt": "I"
    },
    {
        "ListKeHoachThanhTra": [
            {
                "ListDoiTuong": [
                    {
                        "MA_DV_DUOC_TT": "DT01",
                        "TEN_DOITUONG": "Tỉnh Bắc Ninh",
                        "stt": 1.1
                    }
                ],
                "MA_DM_KEHOACH_TT": "KH13072018003",
                "TEN_KEHOACH": "Kế hoạch chính thức",
                "stt": 1
            }
        ],
        "MA_NHOM_TT": "02",
        "TEN_NHOM": "Thanh tra tài chính, bộ ngành",
        "stt": "II"
    }
],
"MA_LOAI_TT": "01",
"TEN_LOAI": "Kế hoạch thanh tra",
"stt": "A"
}
```

Currently, I have a JSON string like this, and I want to display it in a tabular form.

I tried to use the code below, but it just stops at the second ng-repeat, and it's not going any further, so I was wondering how do I do it right?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <tbody ng-repeat="loaiThanhTra in dataTable">                                                                    
        <td>{{loaiThanhTra.stt}}</td>
        <td>{{loaiThanhTra.TEN_LOAI}}</td>

     <tr ng-repeat="nhomThanhTra in loaiThanhTra.ListNhomThanhTra">
        <td>{{nhomThanhTra.stt}}</td>
        <td>{{nhomThanhTra.TEN_NHOM}}</td>
         <tr ng-repeat="keHoachThanhTra in nhomThanhTra.ListKeHoachThanhTra ">
            <td>{{keHoachThanhTra.stt}}</td>
            <td>{{keHoachThanhTra.TEN_KEHOACH}}</td>    
             <tr ng-repeat="doiTuongThanhTra in keHoachThanhTra.ListDoiTuong">
                <td>{{doiTuongThanhTra.stt}}</td>
                <td>{{doiTuongThanhTra.TEN_DOITUONG}}</td>        
             </tr>
         </tr>
    </tr>                             
 </tbody>
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Nesting a `<tr>` element in a `<tr>` element is illegal HTML.

Comment: so what can i do now

Comment: Please show us what you want the table to look like. Since the HTML for the table doesn't make sense, it is unclear what the table you want looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have trs in tds. Use ng-container and row spans on your parent objects.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="loaiThanhTra in dataTable">
  <td>{{loaiThanhTra.stt}}</td>
  <td>{{loaiThanhTra.TEN_LOAI}}</td>

  <tr ng-repeat="nhomThanhTra in loaiThanhTra.ListNhomThanhTra">
    <td rowspan="nhomThanhTra.ListKeHoachThanhTra.length">{{nhomThanhTra.stt}}</td>
    <td rowspan="nhomThanhTra.ListKeHoachThanhTra.length">{{nhomThanhTra.TEN_NHOM}}
    </td>
    <ng-container ng-repeat="keHoachThanhTra in nhomThanhTra.ListKeHoachThanhTra ">
      <td rowspan="keHoachThanhTra.ListDoiTuong.length">{{keHoachThanhTra.stt}}</td>
      <td rowspan="keHoachThanhTra.ListDoiTuong.length">{{keHoachThanhTra.TEN_KEHOACH}}</td>
      <ng-container ng-repeat="doiTuongThanhTra in keHoachThanhTra.ListDoiTuong">
        <td>{{doiTuongThanhTra.stt}}</td>
        <td>{{doiTuongThanhTra.TEN_DOITUONG}}</td>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```